# MaxListenersExceededWarning using trpc with Next.js on Vercel

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, trpc, t3

I built a webapp on Vercel using the t3-stack (next.js, trpc, prisma and nextauth).

Everything was warking well in production until i got a 500 error on a trpc call.

The log showed by vercel is :

> (node:8) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
> leak detected. 11 response listeners added to [ClientRequest]. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

And from that moment every requests shows the same message.
Redeploying the project solved (temporary?) the problem, but i cannot find the source of the error.

The request that triggered the error is :

```
  updateAboutProfile: publicProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        city: z.string().nullish(),
        cognome: z.string().nullish(),
        id: z.string(),
        nome: z.string().nullish(),
        pec: z.string().nullish(),
        phone: z.string().nullish(),
        provincia: z.string().nullish(),
        region: z.string().nullish(),
      })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {

      //update profile in prisma 
      const updatedProfile = await ctx.prisma.profile.update({
        where: { userId: input?.id },
        data: {
          city: input.city || "",
          cognome: input.cognome || "",
          nome: input.nome || "",
          pec: input.pec || "",
          phone: input.phone || "",
          provincia: input.provincia || "",
          region: input.region || "",
        },
      });

      //update profile on the elasticsearch index
      return ctx.elastic.update({
        index: "user_profiles",
        id: updatedProfile.id,
        doc: {
          slug: updatedProfile.id,
          nome: updatedProfile.nome,
          cognome: updatedProfile.cognome,
          provincia: updatedProfile.provincia,
          region: updatedProfile.region,
          shortDescription: updatedProfile.shortDescription,
          image: updatedProfile.image,
          keywords: updatedProfile.keyword,
        },
      });
    }),
```